# sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't find property named "Show" on mapped class Show->shows in this Query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to display a list of shows on a web app that stores venues, artists, and shows.  I've been able to get the venues and artists done but shows is giving me trouble.  It's throwing this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't find property named "Show" on mapped class Show->shows in this Query.
```

To be honest, I have no idea how to approach fixing it, and Googling it returned nothing useful as far as I could tell.  It seems to be looking for the "Show" property but I don't know why.  Can someone explain what I've done wrong/how to fix this?

The section that triggers the error is `def shows()`:

```
class Venue(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'venues'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    city = db.Column(db.String(120))
    state = db.Column(db.String(120))
    address = db.Column(db.String(120))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    genres = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.String))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    website = db.Column(db.String(300))
    seeking_talent = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    seeking_description = db.Column(db.String(120))
    shows = db.relationship('Show', backref='venue', lazy=True)

class Artist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'artists'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    city = db.Column(db.String(120))
    state = db.Column(db.String(120))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    genres = db.Column(db.String(120))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    website = db.Column(db.String(300))
    seeking_shows = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    seeking_description = db.Column(db.String(120))
    shows = db.relationship('Show', backref='artist', lazy=True)        

class Show(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'shows'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artists.id'), nullable = False)
    venue_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('venues.id'), nullable = False)
    start_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Show {} {}>'.format(self.artist_id, self.venue_id)
```

```
def shows():
    # displays list of shows at /shows
    # TODO: replace with real venues data.
    #       num_shows should be aggregated based on number of upcoming shows per venue.
  
    allshows = Show.query.options(db.joinedload('Show.Venue'), db.joinedload('Show.Artist')).all()
    data = list(map(Show.detail, allshows))

    return render_template('pages/shows.html', shows=data)
```

Comment: Just a wild guess here but what happens if you move the line shows = db.relationship... to after when you create your Show class? Also, might just be how you copied it here but is your Show class at the wrong level of indentation?

Comment: Yeah it was just how it got copied.  Indentation is fine, and using that relationship in other functions works just fine.  Tried moving that line, no difference.  I'm pretty confident it's an issue with the code itself.

Comment: One more thing to try... link to "Show" rather than to "shows" (in the documentation, it looks like they link to a class rather than a table name - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/backref.html)

Comment: Looking at the documentation, they're definitely linking to the table because the name is lowercase: backref='user' as opposed to 'User'.

Comment: Interesting, because the first part seems to link to a class: addresses = relationship("Address", backref="user") - 'Address'. One other thing (and I usually just reverse engineer existing schemas rather than create them from scratch) - what is this line supposed to do:    
    shows = db.relationship("shows", backref="artists")  Don't you accomplish that with the previous line, inside the Artist class?  Anyhow, not sure I'm gonna be much help here. Sorry about that.

Comment: @BrandonZemel backref does not refer to a table, it names the linked relationship attribute that will be injected to the class on the other side of the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The error stems from

```
db.joinedload('Show.Venue')
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#relationship-loading-with-loader-options):

> The option accepts either **the string name of an attribute** against a parent, or for greater specificity can accommodate a class-bound attribute directly

Since the current entity of the query being built is `Show`, the option is looking for `Show.Show` first, and all in all for `Show.Show.Venue`. The fix is to use the defined (backref) attribute name:

```
db.joinedload('venue')
```